# Timer in Windows 8.1 - how to mimic Timer(TimerCallback) constructor?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am porting an existing .NET class library that uses [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Threading.Timer.aspx) to a Windows Store app that targets Windows 8.1. The `Timer` class is available, but a few options seem to be missing in relation to the corresponding .NET Framework `Timer`.

In particular, there are only two constructors available in the Windows Store version:

```
public Timer(TimerCallback callback, Object state, int dueTime, int period);
public Timer(TimerCallback callback, Object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period);
```

.NET Framework contains this additional constructor:

```
public Timer(TimerCallback callback);
```

which according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms149618.aspx) sets `dueTime` and `period` to `Timeout.Infinite` and `state` to the `Timer` object itself.

Trying to replace the single argument constructor, I have "naively" tried to pass the `Timer` object into one of the Windows 8.1 constructors, like this:

```
Timer t;
t = new Timer(MyCallback, t, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);  // WILL NOT WORK!!!
```

but of course this only yields the compilation error

> Use of unassigned local variable 't'

There is also no `State` setter or `SetState` method in the `Timer` class, so the `state` cannot be set after construction.

What can I do to fully mimic the full framework's `Timer(TimerCallback)` constructor?

Comment: There's something wrong with this question, what is the relevance of Windows 8.1?  .NET 4.5.1 certainly supports this constructor.  If you are actually talking about a Store app then you can't use this class at all.

Comment: Au contraire, @HansPassant. The `Timer` class was not present in 8.0, but it is indeed included in the 8.1 version of Windows Store apps. You just can't see it in the MSDN documentation (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that these options are acceptable as long as you start the timer manually after the field/property is set, which means using `Timeout.Infinite` for due time which you are.

### State Object

Add a property to a state object:

```
public class MyState
{
   public Timer { get; set; }
}

//create empty state
MyState s = new MyState();
//create timer paused
Timer t = new Timer(MyCallback, s, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
//update state
s.Timer = t;
//now safe to start timer
t.Change(..)
```

### Private Field

```
_t = new Timer(MyCallback, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

MyCallback(object state)
{
  // now have access to the timer _t
  _t.
}
```

### Private Field of an Inner Class

And if one private field is not enough because you want to launch and track multiple, make a new class that wraps a timer. This could be an inner class:

```
public class ExistingClass
{
    public void Launch()
    {
        new TimerWrapper(this);
    }

    private sealed class TimerWrapper
    {
        private readonly ExistingClass _outer;
        private readonly Timer _t;

        public TimerWrapper(ExistingClass outer)
        {
            _outer = outer;
            //start timer
            _t = new Timer(state=>_outer.MyCallBack(this),
                           null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        public Timer Timer
        {
            get { return _t; }
        }
    }

    private void MyCallBack(TimerWrapper wrapper)
    {
        wrapper.Timer.
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndersGustafsson out of interest, which option did you go for?

Comment: It is a little bit embarrassing to admit, but after further investigation I found that `state` was not used in any of the callback methods of the ported code. Therefore I simply replaced the `Timer(callback)` constructor with `Timer(callback, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)`...

Comment: @AndersGustafsson lol was the original code by someone else at least?

Comment: In my defense: yes it was :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure. For example:

```
Timer t = null;

t = new Timer(
    _ => 
    {
        if (t != null)
        {
            // simply use t here, for example
            var temp = t;
        }
    },
    null,
    Timeout.Infinite, 
    Timeout.Infinite);
```

Notice how I test that `t != null`, just in case the timer already calls the callback before it has been assigned to the variable `t`, which might happen if you were to use 0 as a value for dueTime. With a value of Timeout.Infinite, that can't really happen, but I like being defensive in multithreaded scenarios.

In addition to `t`, you can use any other variable that is in scope when the timer is created, as they will all be lifted into the closure (when used in the callback).

If you only want a method to replace the missing constructor, easing your porting effort, here it is:

```
public static Timer Create(TimerCallback callback)
{
    Timer t = null;

    t = new Timer(_ => callback(t), null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

    return t;
}
```

Comment: `Timeout.Infinite` in the due time argument prevents that problem. i.e. callback wont get called till the timer gets started by a later line of code.

Comment: Also I tried this before, it doesn't let you use a value that might not have ben assigned in the closure - it doesn't compile.

Comment: @weston I had noticed those two problems myself just after I posted. The answer has been updated.

Comment: "but I like being defensive in multithreaded scenarios" All your code does is hide a potential null reference exception. Defensive programming isn't about ensuring the program doesn't throw exceptions. If it had an `else` that did something special, or threw a custom exception, that would be better.

Comment: @weston I see your point, but that's not how I was thinking about it. Rather I was thinking something like: if the first iteration of the callback comes too early, simply do nothing and wait for the second iteration. However, as you can see, when this logic is nicely encapsulated in a method, there is no need to protect against a situation that can't happen (because of the Timeout.Infinite).

Comment: @weston The goal of the first code block was to explain the mechanism in a way that might be useful in other but similar situations. I thought it important to note that a function other than this constructor, when used in a similar way, could call the callback before the closure was initialized.