# Can I set the state of an object to the object itself in the constructor call?

Tags: c#, constructor

I am using a pre-built third party class library (think .NET Framework...) that contains a class `Foo` with the following members:

```
public sealed class Foo {
  private object _state;
  public Foo(object state) { _state = state; }
}
```

`Foo` does *not* contain a `public` `_state` setter.

In a specific scenario, I want to set the *state* of a `Foo` object to the object itself.

This will **NOT** compile:

```
Foo f;
f = new Foo(f);   // Compilation error: Use of unassigned local variable 'f'
```

Given the above prerequisites, is there *any* way that I can set the *state* of a `Foo` object to the object itself?

---

**Rationale** The `Timer` class in Windows 8.1 does not contain the `Timer(AsyncCallback)` constructor which assigned the state of the `Timer` object with the object itself. I am trying to port .NET code that contains this `Timer` constructor to a Windows 8.1 class library, so my concern is *How do I pass the object itself to its state member*? This issue is further outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19703993/650012), but I thought it would be more efficient to also pose the principal question above.

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize `f` before using it as an argument ?

Comment: @RédaMattar That would work, however, it would be a separate instance of Foo() not the instance itself.

Comment: @RédaMattar Even if it was initialized, `Foo` doesn't have an overload that takes an instance of `Foo` as a parameter.

Comment: Can you unwrap reference from something else? For example: Handler handler = new Handler(); Foo newFoo = new Foo(handler); handler.f = newFoo;

Comment: @Eugene In my scenario, yes, since I am using the *state* in a callback that I implement myself. However, in the general case the `Foo` class would not know that *state* was a wrapper, so it would potentially not be able to act correctly on *state*.

Comment: @weston worst suggestion in the history of ideas.

Comment: This cannot be done. However, you asked about the Timer before, and got some good answers. What was wrong with those?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten I received those answers *after* I posted *this* question. If it was not for *this* question, those answers would probably not have been provided.

Comment: @weston Using reflection to circumvent the language specification is just about as bad as hacks get. The best answers here would be to suggest a better model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having `Foo`, this isn't possible. You may introduce a facade/proxy object and pass this to the constructor code, that way you can wire things up:

```
public class FooFacade  {
    private Foo foo;
    public void SetFoo(Foo f) { foo = f; }

    // for each property:
    public X Y { get { return foo.Y; } }
}
```

Then you can use this facade:

```
FooFacade ff = new FooFacade();
Foo f = new Foo(ff);
ff.SetFoo(f);
```

Of course this isn't what you wanted in the first place. The drawback of this attempt is that the state of the object is limited to it's public representation.

With reflection, just for completeness:

```
// create an uninitialized object of type Foo, does not call constructor:
var f = (Foo)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(Foo));

// get field:
var stateField = typeof(Foo).GetField("_state", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);

// set value to instance itself, invoke on f:
stateField.SetValue(f, f);
```

Comment: Using reflection like this I will make myself dependent upon the *implementation* of the third-party `Foo` class. Ideally, I would like to use an approach that is *only* dependent upon the API.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson maybe another attempt in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

```
var foo = new Foo(/*params*/);
var fieldInfo = foo.GetType().GetField("_state", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
fieldInfo.SetValue(foo , foo);
```

Comment: `fieldInfo.SetValue(a, a);`? Did you mean `fieldInfo.SetValue(foo, foo);`?

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan: Yeah, fixed.

Comment: Using reflection like this I will make myself dependent upon the *implementation* of the third-party `Foo` class. Ideally, I would like to use an approach that is *only* dependent upon the API.

Comment: The Timer class in Windows 8 is not a .NET class, so this will not work.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: WAT? how relate Timer with my post?

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi Your post answers OP's question, for the case where Foo is a .NET class. But it doesn't help, because OP wants to apply this to a windows runtime class, Timer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your intention correctly you want a timer whose callback references the timer itself.

```
Timer timer = null;
timer = new Timer(() => {
 timer.Stop(); //sample
});
```

Creating an object is done through the `newobj` instruction which atomically allocates and invokes the constructor. Without cooperation from the ctor you cannot get a reference to the unconstructed object. So there's no other way that either this approach, or reflection.

You can extract the above code into a helper method, make `timer` a local variable and then every timer callback will close over its own private and unchanging variable.

```
Timer CreateTimer(Action<Timer> callback) {
    Timer timer = null;
    timer = new Timer(() => {
     callback(timer);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @usr, but this will only be a safe approach as long as I do not re-define `timer`, right? If I move the reference to another object and re-define `timer`, the callback will act on the wrong object, will it not? `var timer2 = timer; timer = new Timer(...);`

Comment: Yes, that is just a question of closure scope. You can extract the above code into a helper method, make `timer` a local variable and then every timer callback will close over its own private and unchanging variable. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it, you don't want to pass the object *itself* as the constructor parameter; you want to pass a lambda that depends on the object. Would that be correct?

In that case, a not-pretty-but-workable workaround would be to add a layer of indirection:

```
Action callback = null;
var timer = new Timer(() => {
    if (callback != null)
        callback();
});
callback = () => {
    // do something
    // do something with timer
}
```

So you'd be passing a lambda to the constructor -- that lambda is valid at the point you call the constructor, although it's not valid to *call* it yet because it depends on the `callback` variable being set. Then you immediately set the `callback` variable to the implementation you want, which can now safely refer to `timer`.

If you're using a timer that fires on a background thread, then there's a possible race condition, where the timer could fire before you initialize your `callback` variable to a non-null value; hence the null check inside the lambda. For timers that fire on the UI thread, that race condition doesn't exist, and the null check could be omitted.

Comment: as far as I can tell, I *can't* pass the object itself to the constructor. The approach you are suggesting here also requires `timer` to no be re-initialized, right? More elaborate answers for the `Timer` question have also "popped" up some minutes ago, please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19703993/650012).

Comment: I don't know what you mean about "requires `timer` to no be re-initialized". The timer is initialized once.

Comment: In your example, yes. But what if I a few lines down move `timer` to another object and re-define `timer`? `var timer2 = timer; timer = new Timer(...);` Then the `callback` method would act on the wrong `Timer`  object.

Comment: Well, sure, that's why you wouldn't do that. Mutable variables are problematic enough to begin with, but they're even worse once you start using functional programming. If it hurts, don't do it.